# Only homepage working laravel on XAMPP

Tags: laravel

I created a laravel 5.4 project i was testing it usin the command 'serve' now i deploy it on xampp only home page is working. when i try to access any pages i get the 404 error 'http://localhost/page1' when i add 'http://localhost/MyApp/public/page1' it works, i added :
RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /MyApp/public/
 to the htaccess file but it doesn't work.

Comment: It would be better for you to set up a virtual host and have the web root for that domain point to the public folder in your app https://laravel.com/docs/master#configuration . I don't use xampp so this might be out of date for the version you're using but it should at least get you on the right track https://delanomaloney.com/2013/07/10/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-xampp/ . Alternatively, you could use `php artisan serve`

Comment: Yeah you need to point your host to the `public` folder

Comment: One waythat you can do this is by adding your site to the vhosyts, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951931/how-to-enable-virtual-host-on-xampp-for-laravel) that details what you need to do:

Comment: thank you i solved the problem by changing the way i call urls, i was using <a href="/Habilite">, I changed it to <a href="{!! url('/Habilite')!!}"> and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem and here's the solution.

I changed the wayl i was using urls from ***href="/Habilite"*** to *** href="{!! url('/Habilite')!!}"***, that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **DocumentRoot** in the **VirtualHost** to :

```
DocumentRoot "/MyApp/public"
```

Make sure to put the **full path** of the public directory

Hope this helps !