# How to remove "public/index.php" on server?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

I m newly working on laravel.

I created laravel project named as "blog" on localhost and for removing `public/index.php`, I followed following process :

1. cut and pasted .htaccess from `public/` folder to root i.e. blog
2. Renamed the server.php to index.php
3. Then I created a test api in api.php route and echoed "Hello World".

Now when I go to project path from my localhost server like:
`localhost/Blog/api/test` then its work properly.

But when I run same on a server like `192.101.111.555`,like :
`192.101.111.555/Blog/api/test` then it showing NOT FOUND.

I am not getting how can I resolve this. And why its working fine on localhost but not working on server ?

Comment: Until you have a domain or a virtual host, I would recommend you to use `php artisan serve` on local and browse at http://localhost:8080 I do **not** recommend to modify index.php or .htaccess

Comment: But I think best practice is to create api is should be without port? Am I correct or incorrect ?

Comment: Does it matter when you work on localhost? If so you can still configure a virtualhost

Comment: I  switched the things from localhost to another server with some IP like above so I think its giving issue due that that only. Because on localhost it was working without any issue

Comment: Here's one of the right way to access from another server  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675683/8068675 And again, I do **NOT** recommend to modify/move index.php or .htaccess

Comment: @MohammedSabir First undo all changes that you did. Second, do you know how to create a virtual host on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You rename server.php but not recommend. This file copy then rename

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have done those settings you will not be able to properly access on the localhost by running `php artisan serve`. So for this, you can install xampp and do the virtual host settings. Check more info at

[How to enable Virtual Host on Xampp for Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951931/how-to-enable-virtual-host-on-xampp-for-laravel).

On the benefit of this is that you don't have to run the `php artisan serve` command again and again.